# What do I have to pay attention when upgrading from Firebird 1.5.6 to 2.5

Tags: firebird

I have problem with my Delphi + Firebird application that works on two Windows 7 machines.
Firebird database used is 1.5.6. and is placed on server machine and the client application is on the other. 
From time to time application is freezeing itself for random time from 30 sec to 2 min. 
Maybe upgradeing to the new version it will stop making problems to me.

Comment: Upgrading will never hurt, but it seems that these freezing are not from FB itself.

Comment: First thing to check - if the application uses the same fbclient.dll/gds32.dll as the server. Freezing might happen if application uses some very old client dll to access DB (f.e. Firebird 0.9, or even earlier - Interbase).
Additionally, I doubt, that upgrade will fix that issue. There has to be something in application or database code that causes that freezing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first take a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/mindthebird/migration-from-firebird-15-to-firebird-25) which was a presentation during firebird conference 2011

Answer (score 0):

Few things I ran into while I was upgrading were:

- reserved word "type" was used as a column name in a table. I had to change it to something esle in database and application code.
- my database used my own UDF, which was compiled in a manner, that made it impossible to use with Firebid 2.5 server. I had to recompile it, and since it was written in C, and I am not experienced C programmer, that was kinda challenge.